# Show Pie Chart Name as Title

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to show the pie chart name on top, bottom, right or left of a pie chart without having to use the labels, like they use in [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo) highcharts demo:

```
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: '<b>Total fruit consumption<b>',
                style: {
                    left: '40px',
                    top: '8px',
                    color: 'black'
                }
            }]
        }
```

The labels have an absolute position in pixels, and for the pies I am using percentages.
When there is a resizing, the labels stay on the same place and the pies move, and I can't get the same relative position in percentage for both.
Example pie:

```
{ data: [{ color: '#31B7C9', name: 'Slice 1', y: 1266364.92333333 }, { color: '#9ED93E', name: 'Slice 2', y: 7284620.73 }, { color: '#DABF12', name: 'Slice 4', y: 2330663.39333333 }], name: 'Pie Chart Name', type: 'pie', center: ["25%", "25%"], showInLegend: true, size: "20%", dataLabels: { enabled: false }}
```

Any idea how to get the pie chart name to display as its title?

Example in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VdDXC/1/).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, a fiddle (not the highchart demo) would be better. May be we can formulate a formula to calculate the position, if you can share the code as to how the pie is plotted under different container dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin that allows to show the pie chart titles [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/3073133-pie-title).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
So it looks like you want to have the same chart as in the demo and not just a pie chart. If that is the case my answer below fails. You will need to use labels and position them.

----Keeping below code for future reference---

Yes,
Use the title property.
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/svkmM/

```
title: {
    text: 'A Title!'
}
```

Comment: It's not the main chart, its a combination chart. Title is required only for the Pie. Correct me if I am wrong @Miguel

Comment: Ah, in that case it will have to be labels. The primary chart uses the title property.

Comment: Yes, title is required only for the Pie @JugalThakkar, the problem of using labels is that I cannot place them dynamically on top left right or bottom of the pie, as a title would.

Comment: @MiguelMarques this is true. Unless you always keep your secondary Pie chart in the same position in all versions of your chart you will always have to generate an x/y postion. If you move the Pie chart around the main chart you will have to move your labels as well.